# Git Repository Managing Operations

Tags: git, repository, gitlab, clone, git-checkout

I am new in git and I need to create some repositories with a couple of restrictions.

Below in the picture described the process what should be done.
Let's say I have **master** repository of MYTOOL in server1.
So, I need to create a new branch **test_branch**, second I need to clone this branch(**master_test_branch**) to different server, where I would like to do checkout to dev repository(dev_test_branch) from this cloned branch.

Basically till now everything is like on the picture below, but here is my special requests.

1. Developers has full access to dev_test_branch.
2. Also they can see **master_test_branch** ONLY, it means that they ever don't aware about other branch(**master, test_branch, ut_branch, prod_branch**).
3. All these branches(**master, test_branch, ut_branch, prod_branch**) have been managing in GitLab, all other branches(**dev_test_branch, master_test_branch**) will use pure git.

In GitLab it is very easy to create a new branch(**test_branch**) step 1.

***My difficulties how do I perform 2 other steps to make it working?***

One more condition, it will be some cases, when admin will decide to do hard push from **test_branch** to **master_test_branch** and developers will decide what to merge into dev_test_branch.

Sorry if I did mixed with terminology naming.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> they can see master_test_branch ONLY, it means that they ever don't aware about other branch

GitLab or not, as soon as you need to see only some branches and not others, you need separate repos:

- one private which includes all branches
- one public (or at least accessible by the dev team in GitLab) which has only the branches you need.
  (and managed outside GitLab, for instance in a [shared network with file protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol), as git bare repos, that way, no server to install, no Apache or ssh. Add a post-receive hook to push to the GitLab repo, and you are set)

You can restrict push access per branches (protected branches), but you cannot in git or GitLab restrict read access: if you can clone/fetch a repo, you are cloning/fetching *all* branches.